# How to loop text file to create string of values

Tags: python, string, readline

I'm somewhat new to python:
I'm trying to write a text file into a different format. Given a file of format:

```
[header]  
rho = 1.1742817531
mu = 1.71997e-05
q = 411385.1046712013 
...
```

I want:

```
[header]  
1.1742817531, 1.71997e-05, 411385.1046712013, ...
```

and be able to write successive lines below that.

Right now, I have the following:

```
inFile = open('test.txt', 'r')  
f = open('test.txt').readlines()  
firstLine = f.pop(0) #removes the first line  
D = ''  
for line in f:  
    D = line.strip('\n')  
    b=D.rfind('=')  
    c=D[b+2:]  
    line = inFile.readline()
```

It returns only the last value, "3".
How do I get it to return a string (which will be saved to a new txt file) in the format I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the number on each tow, on a single row in the output file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex to recover only those lines you want. It depends on how specific you want to be but:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'^.+=')          #[edit]match any string up to '='
result = []
with open('test.txt') as fin:        #use with to auto-close the file when done
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if regex.search(line):
           #slice off last numbers in each line if match (for nums like 12)
           result.append(regex.split(line)[1]) 

mystring = ','.join(result)         #merge list to string with ',' as separator
```

Edit: Just noticed this can be done much more easily for the cases with no need for re module, just replace the if statement with this:

```
        if len(line.split('=')) == 2
            result.append(line.split('=')[1])
```

Comment: The logic is clean, but ultimately much harder to implement, because I simplified the inputs for the sake of posting.  
The real input files looks more like this, where there are inconsistent variable names, and changing number of digits for the variable values:  

rho = 1.1742817531  
mu = 1.71997e-05  
q = 411385.1046712013

Comment: Yeah, regex for parsing is a bit tricky. If you have 'some quantity = num' at each line in the file and want to extract all the nums, the upper regex can be simplified to ```re.compile(r'^.+=')``` with the same effect.

Comment: I'm seeing an "object is not subscriptable" error pointing to the last line. I'm not familiar with this error. :|

Comment: Silly typo on my part.  I should have used parenthesis for the function call in ```join``` should work now. Use ```mystring = mystring.lstrip()``` to remove any leading whitespace.

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f, open('test2.txt', 'w') as f2:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines[1:]:  
        b=line.rfind('=')  
        c=line[b+2:]  
        f2.write(c + '\n')
```

Comment: Close, but this outputs "333", whereas I'm looking for "1 2 3".

Comment: @BrendanMcBreen Edited it try now

Comment: We're closer. We now have a column of values, but I need them space or tab separated, on a single row. I'll also need to be able identify which row I'm writing to, so I don't overwrite this data the next time the script is run.

Comment: @BrendanMcBreen Edited try again

Comment: Hmm. This just "double spaces" the test2.txt file. I need the resulting string in a single row.

Comment: @BrendanMcBreen That's strange